# i m trying to get permission of gallery and camera from the user and want to show that on the profile fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

trying to get permission from the user of gallery and camera want to display that on the fragment but getting resultCode -1 and even cannot get the  onRequestPermissionResult code there. **Getting the result code -1 and RESULT_OK is 0** showing there why ? that lead to break this code...

> this is the profile fragment xml code and want to put the image on the idprofile that is inside the diagonallayout

this is the main Activity on which the fragments are showing

```
package com.example.funsta;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.funsta.Fragment.HomeFragment;
import com.example.funsta.Fragment.NotificationsFragment;
import com.example.funsta.Fragment.PostFragment;
import com.example.funsta.Fragment.ProfileFragment;
import com.example.funsta.Fragment.SearchFragment;
import com.iammert.library.readablebottombar.ReadableBottomBar;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ReadableBottomBar readableBottomBar;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        MainActivity.this.setTitle("My profiles");

        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment());
        transaction.commit();
        readableBottomBar = findViewById(R.id.readableButtomBar);
        readableBottomBar.setOnItemSelectListener(new ReadableBottomBar.ItemSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(int i) {

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                switch (i) {

                    case 0:
                        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new NotificationsFragment());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new PostFragment());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new SearchFragment());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new ProfileFragment());
                        break;
                }
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        
        new ProfileFragment().onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:diagonal="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment.ProfileFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_210mdp"
            diagonal:diagonal_angle="10"
            diagonal:diagonal_direction="left"
            diagonal:diagonal_position="bottom">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/idProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_image" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/black_shades" />

        </com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_70mdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_70mdp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_image"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/changeCoverPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/checked"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
        android:text="Parwez"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16mdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Andriod Devleoper"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14mdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/addFriendView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30mdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30mdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8mdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:backgroundTint="#0474FB"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/commentView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/commentView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30mdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30mdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8mdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:backgroundTint="#F4511E"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/callView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addFriendView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/callView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30mdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30mdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8mdp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:backgroundTint="#04AA0C"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/commentView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add_friend"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/addFriendView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/addFriendView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.66"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/addFriendView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/addFriendView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.47000003" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/comment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/commentView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/commentView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/commentView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/commentView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/call"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/callView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/callView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/callView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/callView" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/commentView">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Followers"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14mdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view12"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="460"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16mdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view12"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral70"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView9" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Friends"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14mdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view13"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view12"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view12" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="120"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16mdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view13"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral70"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Photos"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14mdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view13"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view13" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14mdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/adamina"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/thought"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13mdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
        android:text="My Connections"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16mdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/friendRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is profile Fragment

```
package com.example.funsta.Fragment;

import static android.app.appsearch.AppSearchResult.RESULT_OK;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.funsta.Adapter.friendAdapter;
import com.example.funsta.Model.friendModel;
import com.example.funsta.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private Bitmap selectedImg;
    public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 101;
    public ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> ActivityResultSelectImg;

    RecyclerView friendRv;
    ArrayList<friendModel> friendList;
    ImageView changeCoverPic, idProfile;

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseStorage storage;

    public ProfileFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        friendRv = view.findViewById(R.id.friendRv);
        friendList = new ArrayList<>();
        changeCoverPic = view.findViewById(R.id.changeCoverPhoto);
        idProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.idProfile);
        registerActivityForSelectImg();
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.inaya));
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.profile_image));
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.inaya));
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.profile_image));
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.inaya));
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.profile_image));
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.inaya));
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.profile_image));
        friendList.add(new friendModel(R.drawable.profile));

        friendAdapter adapter = new friendAdapter(getContext(), friendList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        friendRv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        friendRv.setAdapter(adapter);


        changeCoverPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                } else {
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    //startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);
                    ActivityResultSelectImg.launch(galleryIntent);
                    Log.d("incoverpic","correct");
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    public void registerActivityForSelectImg(){


        ActivityResultSelectImg = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {

                        int resultCode = result.getResultCode();
                        Intent data  = result .getData();
                        Log.d("incoverpic","result "+ resultCode+" "+data +" ");
                        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null){
                            try {
                                selectedImg = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),data.getData());
                                idProfile.setImageBitmap(selectedImg);

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    }
}
```

i went through the stackoverflow soln but not getting any help

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I was using RESULT_OK in fragment , But i should use Activity.RESULT_OK.
by doing this i got the correct output .